# If $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}f(t) = 0$, then is it true that $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}f'(t) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ is differentiable and that $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}f(t) = 0$. Does it follow that $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}f'(t) = 0$?

Edit: there are now several great counter examples. No need for new answers. Thanks guys!

Comment: Consider $\sin (e^x)/(1+x^2).$

Comment: It's false. Think of a function that gets very small as you go to infinity, but wiggles more and more.

Comment: Thanks, guys. :-)

Comment: Not sure why this is off-topic. This is not a homework question, just a musing. I am happy to have a few counterexamples in one place (as I'm sure will be future googlers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true; basically, we could tend to zero, but still have very sharp oscillation at infinity. Just take $f(x) = \frac{sin(x^2)}{x}$. Then $|f(x)|$  tends to zero as $x \to \infty$, but taking the derivative, we see that the derivative does not.

Comment: Thank you, Chris!

Answer (score 3):

Nope. 
$$ f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n} e^{-n^2(x-n)^2} $$
is a $C^1(\mathbb{R})$ function, but while $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to +\infty$ (we actually have $f(x)\ll\frac{1}{x}$) the limit $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f'(x)$ does not exist, and the following diagram representing the graph of $f(x)$ over $(0,11)$ should help you in understanding *why*:

$\hspace1in$[image]

Comment: Great example! Thanks, Jack.

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $f(x)=\frac1x \sin (x^2)$. Just because a function is close to zero, that does not imply its slope is close to flat.

Answer (score 1):

Counter example: $$f(t) = \frac{1}{t} \sin t^2 $$ as $$ f'(t) = 2 \cos t^2 - \frac{1}{t^2} \sin t^2 $$ which does not converge as $t \rightarrow \infty$.